# How to return to last prompt after spelling mistake?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, prompt

So I am trying to create little text based game. The problem is that when someone makes a spelling mistake, it will always end the game via the "default" clause where I had to put an alert. Is there any way to make it go back to caveAnswer prompt when someone type incorrect answer?

```js
var caveAnswer = prompt("you are in the cave", "type GO or EXIT").toUpperCase();
        switch(caveAnswer){
            case "GO":
                prompt("some text...", "type blabla");
                break;
            case "EXIT":
                alert("COWARD! HAHAHA!");
                break;
            default:
                alert('I dont understand ' + caveAnswer);
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap in inside a function and have the `default` case call itself to show the prompt again.

```
function ask() {
    var caveAnswer = prompt("you are in the cave", "type GO or EXIT").toUpperCase();

    switch(caveAnswer){
        case "GO":
            prompt("some text...", "type blabla");
            break;
        case "EXIT":
            alert("COWARD! HAHAHA!");
            break;
        default:
            alert('I dont understand ' + caveAnswer);
            ask();
            break;
    }
}

ask();
```